# Убрать страницу checkout Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Хотел бы сделать оплату прямо в корзине одной кнопкой. Подскажите пожалуйста в какую сторону копать, что можно сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно не checkout убирать, а страницу корзины

```
function redirect_to_checkout_if_cart() {
    
           if ( !is_cart() ) return;

           global $woocommerce;

           wp_redirect( wc_get_checkout_url(), 302 );

           exit;
}
    
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_checkout_if_cart' );    
   

function skip_cart_redirect_checkout( $url ) {
    return wc_get_checkout_url();
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_redirect', 'skip_cart_redirect_checkout' );
```

А уже в оставшейся странице checkout изменять, если в корзине остались какие-то важные функции

Comment: Он хочет "оплату **прямо в корзине** одной кнопкой"

Comment: @SeVlad да. он хочет убрать лишний шаг в виде цепочки cart-checkout, но checkout обязательная страница и если убирать из цепочки, то лучше корзину

Comment: @SeVlad и тогда если чекаут заменит корзину, то на страницу оплаты можно будет сразу перейти

Comment: Я-то согласен, что ТС хочет странного. Но... вот так он хочет :)